# should i use extension method or member method in this case?

Tags: c#

for example,

```
        class Aclass
        {
            void method1()
            { 
               int[] a = new int[5]{1,2,3,4,5};
               var b = a.Accumulated().ToArray(); // so that b = {1,3,6,10,15}
            }
        }
```

Currently `Accumulated()` is an extension method. However an equivalent approach I reckon is to define a private member method in Aclass so that `MakeAccumulated(a).ToArray()` gives `{1,3,6,10,15}`.

What is a good practice?

Comment: Do you intend to use the method outside the class?

Comment: no, i don't. surely if i need it outside i have to go for an extension method.

Answer (score 2):

Aclass is a place for methods which make logical sense for Aclass objects; best practice is to not use it as a general store for helper functions. A good rule of thumb is that if a method never references member variables then it might be out of place in the class.

A function on int arrays probably has no place in Aclass. I'd put it in an extension method.

Answer (score 1):

it's not a question of good practice but of preference. both are valid options. if you need the method only in instances of Aclass then I'd limit it to a class method, that's also more obvious to others inspecting the class.

Answer (score 1):

I would choose the *member function* approach, cause `extensions methods`, I personally, choose for something I'm not able to extend, or have a problem to extend to (complexity, not mine code, serialization issues, whatever...). In your case, you have a class written by you, so just extend it, by following *clear* OOP design.

For extension methods, you need to define another class, for someone who is not very familiar with your code, or for you after 2 years, will be not very clear why it's done in that way.

Regards.

Comment: He added an extension method to `int[]` (or possibly `IEnumerable<int>`) which he cannot extend and not to `Aclass`

Comment: Yes, but THERE IS NO any problem to implement a member function, at least looking on code provided and question. That is a point. By me, if you can do it inside class, do it inside class..

Answer (score 1):

If .Accumulated() is only going to be called from instances of Aclass, make it a member of the class.  It wouldn't be practical to have an application-wide extension method for int[] (or Ienumerable as someone else pointed out) if it's only used within an instance of one class.  Keep in mind that extension methods are just for added extensibility.

`public static string Hello(this string Value) { return Value + "Hello"; }`

`string s = "Hello".Hello();`

...is the same as:

`public static string Hello(string Value) { return Value + "Hello"; }`

`string s = Utilities.Hello("Hello");`

Would you put .Hello() in a utility class if you're only going to use it within the instance of another class?  If you use .Accumulated() elsewhere in the application, though, an extension method would work.

Comment: But now that you've done the work to define an Accumulated function on int arrays you should be able to use it anywhere. I find it helpful to have my extension methods listed right in Intellisense because I often use them again even if originally I wasn't planning on it.

Comment: But if you don't need it anywhere, then it shouldn't be accessible anywhere.  If its functionality only proves useful within that class only, make it a private member.  Intellisense will still pick it up.

Comment: I meant for intellisense to present you the option when working with any int[]. The idea of intellisense is that when typing `myintarray.` then a list of all of the things you can do to an int array appears. For this workflow to work the function has to be an extension method.

Comment: Again, if you don't need it for **any** int[], why make it a global extension method for all int[]'s?  If you make it a private member within the class, neither intellisense nor the programmer would know the difference.